# Use Lucene index with Document

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I need to store structured documents, and I need to be able to find them searching into properties.

For example :

```
CREATE CLASS testDocument
INSERT INTO testDocument (my_prop) values ({"name": "James", "age": 23})
INSERT INTO testDocument (my_prop) values ({"name": "John", "age": 51, "tatoos": ["dragon", "jellyfish", "baloon"]})
```

From there I can retrieve data directly, for example :

```
SELECT my_prop.tatoos[0] FROM testDocument WHERE my_prop.age=51
```

But I can't search into the whole object. Is there any way to find the word "dragon" anywhere in documents ?
I tried to add LUCENE Index with no success. What is the type of this kind of property (structured document) if I need to define it ?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: What version of OrientDb are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
SELECT my_prop.name FROM testDocument WHERE my_prop.tatoos contains "dragon"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that way I must know where in the structure the searched string is stored precisely, which I don't. What I need would be something like `SELECT FROM testDocument where my_prop contains "dragon"`, as the underlying structure is not predefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to define the type of this kind of property, you can use embeddedlist for tatoos

```
CREATE CLASS testDocument

create property testDocument.name String 
create property testDocument.age Integer
create property testDocument.tatoos Embeddedlist String

INSERT INTO testDocument content {"name": "James", "age": 23}
INSERT INTO testDocument content {"name": "John", "age": 51, "tatoos": ["dragon", "jellyfish", "baloon"]}
```

[image]

You can use this query

```
SELECT FROM testDocument where age=51 and tatoos contains "dragon"
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

You can use this query

```
select from testDocument where my_prop.toJSON('fetchPlan:*:-1').indexOf("dragon") > -1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but structure is not predefined, each object can have his own one . That's why I need schema-less data. So I can't store them in properties like that.